# Unable to access image data while using jsdom/Jest for testing

Tags: javascript, image, jestjs, jsdom

I am trying to access images while running Javascript tests with Jest.

Background: I have some very old, and possibly badly written code that works just fine in a browser. I am trying to write tests for it so that I can have some confidence it will still behave as expected in the browser as I work on it in future.

After searching around the Jest and jsdom docs, I have established that I need to have Canvas available to be able to access images (I'm using jest-canvas-mock for this). I thought I had got everything set up correctly, but I still cannot access the image data.

I have tried to run some simplified tests - and I was expecting that if the image is loading OK, I would get a value for naturalHeight, but it is currently coming back as 0 (the dataURL is a 17x17 image)

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/no-babel',
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/resources/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/resources/js/cdokb/test/setup.js'],
  testEnvironmentOptions: { resources: "usable", url: "https://image.example.org/" }

}
```

setup.js:

```
import 'jest-canvas-mock';
```

imgload.spec.js:

```
describe('Image Loading', () => {
    it('has access to canvas in jsdom', () => {
        document.body.innerHTML =`
<canvas id="canvas" width="194" height="194"></canvas>
        `;
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        expect(canvas.getContext('2d')).toBeTruthy();
    })

    it('has changed url setting', () => {
        expect(document.URL).toBe('https://image.example.org/');
    })

    it('will load an image into jsdom', () => {
        document.body.innerHTML =`
<img id="image" src="data:image/png;base64,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" width="17" height="17"/>
`;
        var img = document.getElementById("image");

        expect(img.naturalHeight).toBe(17);
    })
})
```

Why do I get 0 as the value of naturalHeight in the 3rd test? And how can I get jsdom to load images with Jest?